# How to find only files, with which command xyz ends successfully?

Tags: find

I'm trying to find all files, that make a given command end successfully (exit code 0).

The find man page says about -exec: `Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.`

Although listed under `Actions`, I thought, that this means, that files that make the given `command` end with 0 will be displayed.

Past uses and trying with `find . -exec true \;` and `find . -exec false \;`, which both gave no output, prove me wrong, though.

A sample invocation would be `find . -exec ./is_dir.py {} \;`, which should print all found directories. (I know, that you can test for this particular case. I couldn't find a combination of tests, that satisfy my actual needs.)

Failing to formulate my problem good enough, searching yielded no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
find . -exec ./is_dir.py {} \; -o -print
```

It will list everything that is not a directory. Assuming that `is_dir.py` is executable (`chmod +x is_dir.py`) and contains something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

if os.path.isdir(sys.argv[1]):
    sys.exit(0)
sys.exit(1)
```

And if `is_dir.py` generates output of its own, you can do:

```
 rm -f nondir.lst
 find . -exec ./is_dir.py {} \; -o -exec echo  {} >> nondir.lst \;
```

so that its outoput doesn't get mixed with the list of names for which `is_dir.py` fails.

Comment: `expr1 -o expr2, Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.` Is found under Operators in the man page.
Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Minix yes, `-o` is for "or"

Comment: @Minux alternatively you can adapt your script to write out a fail list and put everything in a `try:   except:` block.

Comment: I used a `for` loop in the mean time. Will compare outputs after it's done, but I'm confident they will be the same. I will mark your question after it's done running.

Comment: The `is_dir.py` script was just an example. But thanks for going above and beyond :)

Comment: I try to test the things for real, that gives a higher chance I am not making typing errors. So I have a `stackexchange/unix-165669-how-to-find-only-files-with-which-command-xyz-ends-successfully` directory with a real `./is_dir.py` and some `mkdir`-ed directories and some `touched` files. :-)

Comment: Wow. Wish I could give you more than some measly points for that amount of work. Thanks a lot. Everything worked perfectly :)

Comment: @Minix you can ask some more questions, you might get an answer from me, and have chance to do some more upvoting ;-)

Comment: Will probably have to work on a graphical interface with python (again). So I will gladly come back to that offer.